# sorting by imaginary part in R

Tags: r, sorting, complex-numbers

I want to sort a few complex numbers by ascending order of their imaginary parts. I've read the document but I still don't know **how to do this in a single line command by using `sort` function**. (I've tried `r[order(Im(r))]`, which is the answer provided in a similar question, but I want to know how to do this by using `sort`. ) Can anyone help? Thanks.

Comment: Can you give us an example vector of imaginary numbers you want to sort? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 3):

Different orderings of complex numbers are conceivable: e.g. according to their real part, imaginary part, magnitude or polar angle.

To sort according to their imaginary part, it's straightforward to define a custom function. Here is an example:

```
complex_sort  <- function(z) z[order(Im(z))]

z1 <- complex(real = 1, imaginary = 1)
z2 <- complex(real = 2, imaginary = 1)
z3 <- complex(real = 1, imaginary = 2)
complex_sort(c(z1, z2, z3))
#[1] 1+1i 2+1i 1+2i
```

Comment: @Ashley, you might also find it helpful to look at `help("complex")` which has a list of functions you can use to extract different parts of complex numbers in R

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually I've tried this:   `r<-polyroot(c(0,1,2,3,4,5))  r[order(Im(r))]` , but I wonder how to do the same thing by using `sort` in a single command?

Comment: @Aria You can't use `sort` as I explain in my post, hence my definition of function `complex_sort`. So to sort directly you can do `complex_sort(polyroot(c(0,1,2,3,4,5)))`

Comment: Hi! I figure out how to do this now:

`roots<-polyroot(c(0,1,2,3,4,5))
 roots[sort(Im(roots),index.return=T)$ix]
[1]  0.1378323-0.6781544i -0.5378323-0.3582847i
[3]  0.0000000+0.0000000i -0.5378323+0.3582847i
[5]  0.1378323+0.6781544i`